# About angularJS TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, service

```
 angular
    .module('erpos')
    .service('GetBillNoService', ['$http', '$filter', '$cookies', function ($http, $filter, $cookies) {
        return {
            getData: function ($http, $filter, $cookies) {
                var vm = this;

                var billNo = "";
                var date=$filter('date')(new Date(),'yyyy-MM-dd');
                console.log(date);
                date = date.split("-");
                var curDate = date[0].substring(2, 4) + date[1].substring(0, 2);
                HttpService
                    .get('/Company/' + $cookies.get('department') + '/MaterialNo/GetMax')
                    .success(function (data) {
                        switch (data.code) {
                            case 1000:
                                vm.materialIn = data.materialIn;

                                if (vm.materialIn == null) {
                                    vm.billNo = curDate + "0001";
                                } else {
                                    var time = vm.materialIn.maxBillNo.substring(0, 4).toString();
                                    var maxmonth = time.substring(0, 4);
                                    console.log(maxmonth);
                                    if (maxmonth != curDate) {
                                        vm.billNo = curDate + "0001";
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        vm.billNo = (parseInt(vm.materialIn.maxBillNo) + 1).toString();
                                    }

                                }
                                break;
                        }
                    });
                billNo = vm.billNo;
                console.log(billNo);
                return billNo;
            }
        }

    }]);
```

I want to get a billNo with this service,and then pass the billNo to the controller ,but errors appear that

> 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined'

I found the error in the 'get' is the property of cookies, but I have injected it already, so who can tell me what is going wrong?

Comment: `HttpService` isn't injected

Comment: I'd like to add that you're still using `.success()`. I highly suggest switching over to `.then()`. The first notation is deprecated and is completely removed in AngularJS version 1.6.0.

Answer (score 4):

change `HttpService.get` to `$http.get` will solve your problem.

Comment: I am trying to follow your way to do it,but it still report the same error.

Comment: @wqvincent how did you call `GetBillNoService .getData`?

Comment: vm.new_materialIn.billNo=GetBillNoService.getData();

Comment: @wqvincent OK, based on the way you call it, you have to change `getData: function ($http, $filter, $cookies){...}` to `getData: function(){...}` and use the `$http` you injected.

Comment: thank you for your answer,but now there is another error:I still cannot get the billNo,I console.log the "GetBillNoService.getData()";but it shows that "undefined"

Comment: @wqvincent $http.get is an `asynchronous call`, so you won't get its result immediately, you have to deal with the result in its `success` callback.

Comment: GetBillNoService.getData().success(function(response){
                    vm.materialIn.billNo=response.data;
                })

Comment: I did it in the callback ,but it shows that   Cannot read property 'success' of undefined

Comment: @wqvincent no, you can't do it this way. please do some research about how to define a service.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call `.get` on `HttpService`. You didn't [inject](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) this service on your controller, that is why it is `undefined`.

#### Solution 1

Use `$http.get` instead of `HttpService.get`, this, is the $http service provided by Angular.

```
$http.get('/Company/' + $cookies.get('department') + '/MaterialNo/GetMax')
```

#### Solution 2

Inject `HttpService` in your controller to use your own.

```
.service('GetBillNoService', ['$http', '$filter', '$cookies', 'HttpService', 
                     function ($http,   $filter,   $cookies,   HttpService) {
```